# Write results to server file

Tags: javascript, php, json, xml, csv

I've been trying to find a simple solution to write results from a json query result.

I have a file that gets statistics from a json query and document.write 's it.

I need those results printed in a csv or xml file on the server.

I realize I cannot use javascript because of security risk. But I understand that I could use PHP . Or maybe there is even a simpler solution to this.

Since im very new to this, I was wondering if someone can help me figure this out.

My code is below :

```
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>


</head>


<script>
        var query = {
  "query": [
    {
      "code": "Sveitarfélag",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "Alls"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "Aldur",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "Alls"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "Ár",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "18"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "Kyn",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "Alls"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "response": {
    "format": "csv"
  }
};
        query = JSON.stringify(query);
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
          url: "http://px.hagstofa.is/pxis/api/v1/is/Ibuar/mannfjoldi/2_byggdir/sveitarfelog/MAN02001.px",
          data:query,
          success: function(json) {
                document.write(json);
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

** ***EDIT*** **
Just to clarify :

I have an application that can only read xml or csv. So I need the results from the above file to be printed and saved into a file : "/server/user/htdocs‌​/xml-or-csv/File.csv"

or xml

Comment: You want to _convert_ your json to csv or just send it to the server? Didnt get the task, pls clarify

Comment: I have an application that can only read xml or csv. So I need the results from the above file to be printed and saved into a file :  "/server/user/htdocs/xml-or-csv/File.csv"

Comment: after you post the data, you have to handle the saving part in the server side. `file_put_contents("filename", serialize($data))`

Comment: @KaushalNiraula Can you show me a complete solution please ?

Comment: in your ajax request, do  `url: "xyz/save.php", data:{'data',JSON.stringify(query)}` and in your save.php file, do `$data = $_POST['data']; file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/pathto/file.xyz',json_decode($data));`

Comment: @KaushalNiraula : Thank you for your response, but im sorry, i dont follow you here, do you want me to remove the url I have in my ajax request and replace it with "xyz/save.php"  ? ... but how do I get the results from my request then ?

Comment: @KaushalNiraula If you click the blue button on the bottom of the page "Answer question" and show me the code for those two files I need, and it works . Then i'll mark the answer as the correct one. :-)

Comment: @KaushalNiraula : Im going crazy here ,,,, tried all kinds of solutions but none work. It sounded like you knew how to do this.... Would you be so kind to answer in detail so that I can stop tearing my hair out here :-) Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do put the php code in the endpoint which handles "http://px.hagstofa.is/pxis/api/v1/is/Ibuar/mannfjoldi/2_byggdir/sveitarfelog/MAN02001.px"

if you save this code as index.php and change the post url for ajax to index.php, you will have a working demo on how to save a file remotely via ajax post

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['data'])){
        $data = $_POST['data'];
        echo $data;
        //instead of xyz.csv, you need to give the complete path of the file to where you want to store
        file_put_contents("xyz.csv", $data);
    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "jquery.js"></script>

        <script>
            var query = {
                "query": [
                {
                    "code": "Sveitarfélag",
                    "selection": {
                        "filter": "item",
                        "values": [
                        "Alls"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "code": "Aldur",
                    "selection": {
                        "filter": "item",
                        "values": [
                        "Alls"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "code": "Ár",
                    "selection": {
                        "filter": "item",
                        "values": [
                        "18"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "code": "Kyn",
                    "selection": {
                        "filter": "item",
                        "values": [
                        "Alls"
                        ]
                    }
                }
                ],
                "response": {
                    "format": "csv"
                }
            }

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#btn').click(function(){
                console.log({'data':JSON.stringify(query)});

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://px.hagstofa.is/pxis/api/v1/is/Ibuar/mannfjoldi/2_byggdir/sveitarfelog/MAN02001.px",
                    data:{'data':JSON.stringify(query)},
                    success: function(json) {

                    }
                });


            })  


            })



        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn">Click</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it does not work, I set the complete path to the location where I want the csv file to be written , and then changed the jquery location as well... But I get a 404 error on the POST. It does not give any results or save any file. Have you tested this ?

Comment: what did you change the jquery location to? The backend which handles the url you enter in jquery must handle the saving of file. You cant do that from jquery. Jquery only passes the data to the server. You have to get and save what you get from jquery post **in the server**

Comment: I changed it first to a local path **on the server** and then I changed it to `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`   ,,, both ways did not work. I also tried the latest version....